# Keyevent doesn't work

Tags: android, python, keyevent, appium

I have a problem with keyevents when I try to press the home button.

Where is the bug?

```
driver.execute_script("mobile: keyevent", {"keycode": 3})
```

I use python and appium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem were extra spaces.
The code should look like this:

```
driver.execute_script("mobile: keyevent",{ "keycode": 3 })
```